# Acer Iconia Tab A100 not connected to XP

Tags: android-widget

I installed on PC/XP USB driver for Acer Tab A100 from acer.com
plugin A100 to PC
Hardware A100 regognized as ACER MTP
THEH:

"Cannot install this Hardware
There was a problem installing This hardware Acer MTP
An error occurred during the installation of the device
The required section was not found in the INF"

Please, explain where i'm wrong..

Thanks, Victor

Answer (score 2):

I had some of the same problems on Win 7 x64.  The solution boiled down to I went to Acer support and **downloaded the USB drivers for the A500 and installed those**.  I can now see the device storage, the MicroSD storage on the device and connect with adb (currently debugging through the Eclipse plugin). So it looks like those drivers do the trick, I think their installer for the A100 USB drivers is just plain junk right now.

One problem remains: I was getting a .Net error with Acer Sync when I plugged in the device, but I really don't care about that, so I just uninstalled that bad boy.

Wasted the whole afternoon yesterday on the phone and chatting with Acer, don't make that mistake, when it comes to connecting up a dev environment they are clueless.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Might be my A100 had a different hardware ID. Even tried the manual install approach and Windows 7 didn't find appropriate drivers in the 'tanb' install folder

Answer (score 1):

It´s the only way to connect it, installing USB drivers for the A500 requires you to have installed windows media player 11.